# Textbox Won't Update Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can't get my textbox to update the database. The changes look like they are saved (they are saved on the page) and the modal pop up goes away, but the text that I tried to change in the database stays the same.

```
Protected Sub SubmitEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim myControl As Control = FindControl("txtData")
    If (Not myControl Is Nothing) Then
        Dim UpdateSql As String = "UPDATE Picklist SET (Data) = @Data WHERE PicklistID = @PicklistID"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection
        (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)
            Using sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(UpdateSql, cn)
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", myControl))
                cn.Open()
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    Else
    End If
End Sub


 <asp:TabPanel ID="tab2"  runat="server" HeaderText="Descriptions">
<HeaderTemplate>Descriptions</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ul class="info">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvDescriptions" runat="server" 
          DataSourceID="dsAdminMarketingDescriptions" DataKeyNames="MarketingID">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="item">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ViewDescriptionButton" runat="server">
                <%# Eval("Title")%>
                </asp:LinkButton>

               <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteDescriptionButton" runat="server"  
                Style="float:right;" AlternateText="" 
                ImageUrl="../../images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" 
                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this 
                description?')" />

                <asp:Panel ID="ViewDescriptionPanel" runat="server"
                  CssClass="DescModalPopup">                                   
                <div class="PopupHeader">View Description -- <%#Eval("Title") %>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelDescriptionButton" runat="server" 
                  ImageUrl="../../images/cancel.png" AlternateText="" 
                  Style="float:right;"/>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="EditDescriptionButton" runat="server" 
                   ImageUrl="../../images/edit.png" AlternateText="" 
                   Style="float:right;" CommandName="Edit" AutoPostBack="false" />
                </div>

                    <asp:Label ID="Description" runat="server" style="padding:2px;">
                    <%# Eval("Data")%>
                    </asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel> 

                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ViewDescriptionModal" runat="server" 
                  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false" 
                  DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" 
                  PopupControlID="ViewDescriptionPanel" 
                  TargetControlID="ViewDescriptionButton" 
                  CancelControlID="CancelDescriptionButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender> 


                <asp:Panel ID="EditDescriptionPanel" runat="server" 
                  CssClass="DescModalPopup">

                <div class="PopupHeader">Edit Description -- <%# Eval("Title")%>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Cancel" runat="server" 
                  ImageUrl="../../images/cancel.png" AlternateText="" 
                  Style="float:right;"/>
                </div>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                     Text='<%# Eval("Data")%>'>
                    </asp:TextBox><br />
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitEdit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelEdit" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </asp:Panel>

                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="EditDescriptionModal" runat="server" 
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false" 
                DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="true" 
                PopupControlID="EditDescriptionPanel" 
                TargetControlID="EditDescriptionButton">
                </asp:ModalPopupExtender>            
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

**UPDATE: I tried using a try catch to get an error message, but it didn't work.**

```
Protected Sub SubmitEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim myControl As Control = FindControl("txtData")
    If (Not myControl Is Nothing) Then
        Try
            Dim UpdateSql As String = "UPDATE Picklist 
                                       SET (Data) = @Data 
                                       WHERE Title = @Title"
            Using cn As New SqlConnection
             (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
             ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)
                Using sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(UpdateSql, cn)
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", 
                     DirectCast(myControl, TextBox).Text))
                    cn.Open()
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
                cn.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message())
        End Try
    Else
    End If
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

**UPDATE: Figured it out. Here is the code behind, all other code stayed the same**

```
Protected Sub SubmitEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    For Each item As ListViewDataItem In lvDescriptions.Items
        Dim txtData As TextBox = DirectCast(item.FindControl("txtData"), TextBox)
        Dim ltlTitle As Literal = DirectCast(item.FindControl("ltlTitle"), Literal)
        Dim UpdateSql As String = "UPDATE Picklist 
                                   SET Data = @Data 
                                   WHERE Title = @Title"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection
        (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)
            Using sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(UpdateSql, cn)
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", txtData.Text))
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Title", ltlTitle.Text))

                cn.Open()
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using
            cn.Close()
        End Using
    Next
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the line:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", myControl))
```

to

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Data", myControl.Text))
```

**Update:**

Since the textbox is in a listview itemtemplate, you also need to change how it is discovered by looking at the currently selected list item. To do this, change the following line:

```
Dim myControl As Control = FindControl("txtData")
```

to:

```
Dim myControl As TextBox = DirectCast(lvDescriptions.Items(lvDescriptions.SelectedIndex).FindControl("txtData"), TextBox)
```

I have also updated the sqlParameters assignment to remove the DirectCast since we are now declaring the control as a TextBox (but it still needs to be updated to use the Text property from the original code).

Comment: I didn't scroll to the right to view all of the update text; you are missing the parameter for @PickListID. I suspect that an exception is being thrown that you are not seeing; I would strongly suggest wrapping the contents of the click event in a try/catch statement, then set a breakpoint in the catch to see what error is being generated and address that error.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was the PicklistID as well so I changed it to @Title, because that is the other thing that the modal is based on, but I still can't update the database. Check edits above, I'm not sure that I used the try catch right.

Comment: The issue is that you still aren't setting the @Title parameter anywhere: sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Title",                    DirectCast(myTitleControl, TextBox).Text)). Your use of the try catch is correct, but you're never going to see the problem because the last statement (response.redirect) is always executed. You can either add a label to the page for testing purposes and store the message in the label or set a breakpoint inside the catch statement and inspect the exception that is thrown in the debugger.

Comment: I stepped through the code and it stopped at the If statement so I removed it, not sure why it was there. Then it stopped at the @Data parameters line and said `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` So that means it can't find my editing textbox?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means and I should have taken a closer at your HTML declaration to realize this. See the updated answer for the additional change to make.

Comment: I changed the code to reflect the changes you made, and now when I step through I get an error that says `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index` I have never seen this one before.

Comment: I figured it out, put code up in the original post. Thank you for all your help! It was soooo frustrating!